# Configuring SocialAuthNet

Tags: .net

I am trying to configure SocialAuthNet to be able to extract profile data from LinkedIn. I am trying to get started using the Quickstart_Guide provided by SocialAuthNet themselves, which can be found at:

[Quickstart guide](https://code.google.com/p/socialauthnet/wiki/Quickstart_Guide#Create_a_new_web_application)

I have followed all of the steps provided. However, I am receiving this error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Thanks